# How to call static async function in the below code snippet

Tags: c#, async-await

```
public static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService( string pstrRequest)
        {
            ServiceConnect objServiceConnect = new ServiceConnect();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var scoreRequest = new
                {
                    Inputs = new Dictionary<string, InputOutputTable>() {
                        {
                            "input1",
                            new InputOutputTable()
                            {
                                ColumnNames = new string[] {"Assignment group", "Short description"},
                                Values = new string[,] {  { "", pstrRequest },  { "", "" },  }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                    }
                };
                const string apiKey = "Some API Key"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Some Uri");

                // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                // For instance, replace code such as:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                // with the following:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);
}
```

// I am calling function like this

```
ServiceConnect.InvokeRequestResponseService("xyz").Wait();
```

Here Wait() returns viod so I am not able to return anything from here. But I have to add Wait to get task completed.
Could anyone guide how can I get response of function or what is the other way to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

To get response of function change return type to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and return the response.

Given that the response is the only thing that needs the await you can remove the `async` key work and just return the response task

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeRequestResponseService( string pstrRequest)
{
    ServiceConnect objServiceConnect = new ServiceConnect();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var scoreRequest = new
        {
            Inputs = new Dictionary<string, InputOutputTable>() {
                {
                    "input1",
                    new InputOutputTable()
                    {
                        ColumnNames = new string[] {"Assignment group", "Short description"},
                        Values = new string[,] {  { "", pstrRequest },  { "", "" },  }
                    }
                },
            },
            GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            }
        };
        const string apiKey = "Some API Key"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Some Uri");

        // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
        // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
        // For instance, replace code such as:
        //      result = await DoSomeTask()
        // with the following:
        //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)

        return client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);
    }
}
```

With that you can call the function

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await ServiceConnect.InvokeRequestResponseService("xyz");
```